# Unicode string (in @variable) doesn't match in LIKE?

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL  "N" function in where clause  doesn't work properly.
This is my SQL Code

```
SELECT  
    [11 Lab Data Detail].LineDesc, 
    [11 Lab Data Detail].ProductSample, 
    [11 Lab Data Detail].LotNo,
    [11 Lab Data Detail].TestDesc,
    Avg([11 Lab Data Detail].TestRes) AS [TestRes]  
into 
    [21 Test Result]
FROM 
    [11 Lab Data Detail]  
GROUP BY 
    [11 Lab Data Detail].LineDesc, 
    [11 Lab Data Detail].ProductSample, 
    [11 Lab Data Detail].LotNo, 
    [11 Lab Data Detail].TestDesc 
HAVING
    [11 Lab Data Detail].LineDesc=@LineDesc AND 
    [11 Lab Data Detail].ProductSample=@ProductSample AND 
    [11 Lab Data Detail].LotNo=@LotNo AND 
    [11 Lab Data Detail].TestDesc like N'%' + @TestDesc + '%'
```

Here if i use constant value for @testDesc - like
**like N'SP (C)'** then it works properly.

Comment: Can you tell us one value of `@TestDesc` that doesn't work (with Unicode characters in it). Also, please say what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. when @TestDesc is 'SP (ºC)' it won't select the result. If it has non unicode value like 'IV (Manual)' it selects the result.

Comment: Basic testing show that it works. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112135/ There is obviously something else that makes it not work for you.

Comment: How are you initialising the variable? Could it be that the environment that passes the value to be stored is actually non-Unicode?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I got the solution. the problem is in how i execute the Stored procedure. Actually i execute this using pass-through query in access. there i add 'N' in query and everything is ok now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is the column [11 Lab Data Detail].TestDesc a varchar or nvarchar data type or something else?